# DDD for web application, should I put a rich domain object into presentation layer?

Tags: java, session, domain-driven-design, session-variables

I am trying to develop a web application by DDD. But in the best practice, I am not sure should I put rich domain objects into web session directly? For example: as the [link](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/02/domain-driven-design-spring-aspectj.html) suggest, it put the EntityManager to the domain object, I think it is not good if I want to put the domain object into the web session.

So, could you share some real experiences to apply DDD to a web application? especially how to deal with the rich domain objects with web session? and is there any good demo application (by Java) I can reference?

Thanks,
Leon

---

Dear MikeSW, MaxS, thanks for your valuable answers.

So, in practice, if I use DDD, I still have to crate an shallow(anemic) object model, or DTO, to share data between presentation layer and service(business) layer.

Is my understanding correct?

If there is any good reference application or articles that talk about similar architecture, please kindly let me know.
I have tried to find some, but hoped to see more.

Thanks, Leon

Comment: What do you mean by "web session"?

Comment: I mean this: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html

Comment: I share many of yours doubts, i think that the basic problem starts at builing the correct domain model, that clearly hasn't to be anemic and has some behaviour. This is a good place for start : http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html, and i heart about DDD quicly (is a quick tour of DDD metolodogy and practiques presetented by his author, Eric Evans).

Answer (score 4):

Domain objects (or any complex object) shouldn't be put in Session for both technical (resource waste) and semantical reasons. Session is not ment to be a Cache, but a holder of tmeporary user data. Store the object id maybe in the Session and then use the Repository to retrieve the actual object. The repository may cache things if required.

Answer (score 3):

Domain Objects have nothing to do with Presentation model!
With Domain Driven Design, you don't have to worry about how your data will be displayed neither the way they will be persisted. The only thing you have to focus on, is to model your Business.

Moreover it's not a best practice to expose your business model to the front-end users. They don't have to know how your business runs, what are your business rules or anything related to business.
That's what ViewModel or DTO's are for. These are Presentation layer entities, built to be displayed or exposed via any kind of web services.

For other reasons, it's not a good option to have your DB model looks like your business model. A DB engine will have to deal with other concerns that will lead you to organize the way your data will stored differently than the way you design your Domain.

Concerning Session, keep it as light as possible. As @MikeSW said:

> Session is not ment to be a Cache

Let's say you want to store every entities in the Session. It might easily reach about 250kb. It might not seem big at first glance, but what if your server is hit by 10,000 different users? Your Session size will grow dramaticaly up to 2,3Gb! Only for Session data! This will obviously lead to performance issues.

**EDIT --- for your new questions**

> So, in practice, if I use DDD, I still have to create a
>   shallow(anemic) object model, or DTO, to share data between
>   presentation layer and service(business) layer.

Well, let's say you have to built an MVC project.
Your `Controllers` will handle the requests, they will call a `ModelBuilder` to get the right `Model` and return it to the `View`.
This is up to the `ModelBuilder` to call your `Domain Services`. Those services will return domain objects that you'll have to map to the `View Model`.

This will work somehow the same if you're exposing some web services.
Web Services have contracts that are `Interfaces`. Those contracts are defining the methods exposed by the web service and the objects that are manipulated (DTO). This is up to the class that implements the contract interface, to call your `Domain Services`. Those services will return domain objects that you'll have to map to `DTO`.

> If there is any good reference application or articles that talk about
>   similar architecture

DDD is not any technique or architecture. It's all [about](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design):

> Defining the ubiquitous language meaning that the domain model should
>   form a common language given by domain experts for describing system
>   requirements, that works equally well for the business users or
>   sponsors and for the software developers.

Have a look at SO Questions and articles related to Java n-tiers architecture if you want to know how to design your application.

Comment: DDD is cleary a methodology my friend, a methodology, a way of thinking, pointed by Eric Evans; don't we agree? It states a methodology, a global vision on how to disaggregate a system in parts, and logically it comes with tools (abstract tools) and techniques.